# Changing the feedback branch in Buck converter

Tags: voltage, power, analog, dc, buck

I am trying to implement output voltage remote sensing in Buck converter. I am taking the feedback from the load side. I have made a circuit which can act as a local or remote as per the active components. [image: image attached]. If C5 is removed, it will act as remote sensed and if R1 and R2 are removed and soldered in place of C6 and C7 then it is local sensing. This is giving me good steady state results in case of remote sensing.
My question is what can be the impact on load transients peak deviations of the capacitive branch C6 and C7 with R1 and R2?

Comment: This is not how a remote sense should like. If you want this, you should use an opamp.

Comment: Yes, I completely understand your point. But remote sensing is taking feedback from the remote load, which is not in the case of local sensing.

Comment: 1st: Why would you have a changeable  feedback position? 2nd: Having a capacitor divider on high frequency output is a terrible idea, where you get it? 3rd: What the IC manufacturer suggests in his app. notes?

Comment: The schematic was finalized for local sensing purpose and released in the market. I am trying to add remote sensing along with local sensing. I am analysing the effects. I am trying out different ideas so Cap divider with ressitive divider is giving me good steady state results. No, it is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Let me know, if I am not clear at any point.

Comment: I'll second @MarkoBuršič's 2nd point. A capacitive divider for a DC feedback is not such a good idea. Plus, why would a 10 pF cap, in parallel with a 1000 pF cap, make any difference when added/removed?

Comment: Modify schematic to include Rs, L and C of cable and load.  Simulate transfer function of filter in gain phase from both load and outputs as a source. Use 8nH / cm for each wire and C depends on cable if UTP, STP etc.  All Universal laptop chargers use lossy wires to plug, so they use a 3rd wire from plug to regulate that “remote” output.  Analyze those designs and also Lambda’s old linear designs for remote control and sensing for the filters used for resonance or phase margin design details.

Comment: I need further clarifications. In case of remote sensing,
The Transfer function (Vfb/Vout) of feedback resistive branch will be R2/(R1+R2)
The transfer function (Vfb/Vconv) of feedback capacitive branch will be C1/(C1+C2)
Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

If the design doesn't support it, then don't run remote sense like this, in most DC DC converters it will cause instabilities in the feedback loop. I tried this years ago thinking I could cause the loop to neglect the wire resistance, what I got instead is a unstable feedback loop because of the added series inductance. The biggest problem is placing the feedback line after the filter caps significantly changes the switching voltage that the feedback line sees and also the time that it takes for the comparator/switching circuit to see the inductor get switched on and off.

If you do run a remote sense like this, then you need to put it in a spice sim and check for stability. Make sure you have a good model of the ESL and ESR on the feedback trace.

Keep in mind that my remote sense line was less than an inch away after the filter caps and it caused me some real problems.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
The system is stable. I have run the simulation on Advanced Design system. How can I mathematically explain the transfer function of the sense lines and remote power connection? It might help me to explain few things.

Comment: What is your DC to DC converter? Did you use trace parasitics in your sim? It is really difficult to add the parasitics into the transfer function